# Grok pattern to match email address

Tags: pattern-matching, logstash-grok, grok

I have the following Grok patterns defined in a pattern file

```
HOSTNAME \b(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62})(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*(\.?|\b)
EMAILLOCALPART [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_.+-=:]+
EMAILADDRESS %{EMAILLOCALPART}@%{HOSTNAME}
```

For some reason this doesn't compile when run against http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ with the following input, it simply returns "Compile error"

```
Node1\Spam.log.2016-05-03   171 1540699703 03/May/2016 00:00:01 +0000  INFO  [http-bio-0.0.0.0-8001-exec-20429] EngagementServiceImpl logDefault 192.168.1.122 77777777777777777 DAMIEN@DAMIEN.COM > initiated Stuff: 8675309, provider: 8675309, member: 8675309
```

Is there some reason I'm getting a compile error / will this even match the email in that log line?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you can use `(?<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*)`. No idea why that fails, but `+-=` is definitely a wrong pattern, the `-` should not be a range operator (must be escaped or put at the end of the char class). Also, you need no `\b` in the resulting regex since `@` is a non-word char, and `[0-9A-Za-z]` matches a word char.

Comment: That doesn't fail for me, but it doesn't match the email address in the string, does it work for you?

Comment: `(?<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*)` (and `(?<email>[\w.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:[.](?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*)`) works at http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/. BTW, https://github.com/rgevaert/grok-patterns/blob/master/grok.d/postfix_patterns defines the email pattern differently: `EMAILADDRESS %{EMAILADDRESSPART:local}@%{EMAILADDRESSPART:remote}`

Comment: Awesome, these all worked for me... can you turn this last comment into an answer since that resolved my question?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-‌​9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*)
```

or:

```
(?<email>[\w.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:[.](?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z‌​-]{0,62}))*)
```

They work at [grokdebug.herokuapp.com](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com). 
BTW, https://github.com/rgevaert/grok-patterns/blob/master/grok.d/postfix_patterns defines the email pattern differently: `EMAILADDRESS %{EMAILADDRESSPART:local}@%{EMAILADDRESSPART:remote}`, it may also work.