# Filter message based on String

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have below logs in same log file
`2019-11-23T14:38:43.495 backendorg [http-nio-8080-exec-45] INFO  http-nio-8080-exec-45 SessionController http://localhost:8080/ABC/session/login abc.nayak@zinier.com backendorg`

`2019-11-23T14:38:44.235 backendorg [http-nio-8080-exec-45] INFO  http-nio-8080-exec-45 SessionController userSession: backendorg 16CFAFCCFB14D9A3 16E978545E17BFEC 16E978545E1452FF`

using below filter to parse the messages above based on String "**userSession**".

```
 input {
      file {
            tags => ["stacktrace"]
            type => "error_logs"
            path => ["/Users/znrind-a0053/Downloads/logs/zapp-audit.log"]
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/tmp/sincedb_file"
            codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} "
            negate => true
            what => previous
            }
      }

}
filter {

      if "userSession" in [message]{
        grok {
        match => [ "message",
                 "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp_match} %{USERNAME:orgId} (\[%{DATA:thread}\])?( )?%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:zhost} %{JAVAFILE:javaClass} %{URI:url}%{SPACE}(?<email>[\w.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:[.](?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z‌​-]{0,62}))*)%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:orgnisation}"]
          }
      } else {

      grok {
      match => [ "message",
               "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp_match} %{USERNAME:orgId} (\[%{DATA:thread}\])?( )?%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:zhost} %{JAVACLASS:javaClass} %{USERNAME:logmessage}:?%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:orgnisation}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:loginUserId}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:sessionId}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:txnId}"]
        }
      }
}
output {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "localhost"
            index => "logs"
        }
        stdout{codec => json}
}
```

But receiving GROK parser error. Any suggestion highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `filter`:

```
filter {

      if "userSession" in [message]{
        grok {
        match => [ "message",
                 "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp_match} %{USERNAME:orgId} (\[%{DATA:thread}\])?( )?%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:zhost} %{JAVAFILE:javaClass} %{USERNAME:logmessage}:?%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:orgnisation}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:loginUserId}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:sessionId}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:txnId}"]
          }
      } else {

      grok {
      match => [ "message",
               "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp_match} %{USERNAME:orgId} (\[%{DATA:thread}\])?( )?%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:zhost} %{JAVAFILE:javaClass} %{URI:url}%{SPACE}(?<email>[\w.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:[.](?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z‌​-]{0,62}))*)%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:orgnisation}"]
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For email you have to use ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38336117/11640763))

```
(?<email>[a-zA-Z0-9_.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:\.(?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-‌​9A-Za-z-]{0,62}))*)
```

or

```
(?<email>[\w.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:[.](?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z‌​-]{0,62}))*)
```

Thus, your match will become

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp_match} %{USERNAME:orgId} (\[%{DATA:thread}\])?( )?%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:zhost} %{JAVAFILE:javaClass} %{URI:url}%{SPACE}(?<email>[\w.+=:-]+@[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z-]{0,62}(?:[.](?:[0-9A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z‌​-]{0,62}))*)%{SPACE}%{USERNAME:orgnisation}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But my question was above if-else doesn't work with string. getting _grokparsefailure.

Comment: Because your match statement is incorrect. It does not compile. Please check again.

Comment: i have edited my post with complete config file. Still getting same error after use your solution. Kindly let me know what wrong with this.